# What are some of the approaches of defining joint pdf under sum constrain?

Tags: uncertainty, constraint

For example, we have three random variables,

$x_1 = Uniform(10,20)$

$x_2 = Uniform(20,40)$

$x_3 = Uniform(50,150)$

which follows the condition $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 100$

I am looking for a joint pdf of the three R.V. that takes the sum constraint into account while sampling the random variables independently.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** It is not clear to me what you are asking. Terms like 'uncertainty measure' and 'taking into account' are sort of vague.

Here is a
simulation of 100,000 runs of the experiment you propose.

```
set.seed(1234);  m = 10^5
x1 = runif(m, 10, 20)
x2 = runif(m, 20, 40)
x3 = runif(m, 50, 100)
s = x1 + x2 + x3
mean(s);  var(s)
[1] 119.9747      # aprx E(S)
[1] 249.1283      # aprx Var(S)
[1] 0.11635       # aprx P(X < 100)
```

It seems that the mean of the sum is $E(S) \approx 120,$ also that $Var(S) \approx 250,$ so $SD(S) \approx 16.$

You may have studied formulas that would enable you to find exact values
for the mean, variance, and standard deviation of the sum. (To start: do you know how to find the mean and variance of a uniform distribution?)

A histogram of the 100,000 resulting totals is shown below:

```
hist(s, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Just from that we can see that $S=100$ is not an unusual value
for $S.$ Certainly, it is noticeably below average, but not at all a rare value.
Almost 12% of the simulated values of $S$ fell below 100.

***Maybe*** you're supposed to say something like "$100$ is more than one standard
deviation below the mean but not as far as two standard deviations below the mean." If I were teaching the course, I can imagine asking for something like that. (But I'd try to ask a clearer question.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking either, but here is a way to sample these random variables.

We can rewrite your random variables as $$X_1= \ \ 10   U_1+10,$$
$$X_2= \ \ 20   U_2+20,$$ $$X_3 = 100  U_3 + 50,$$ where the $U_i$ are uniform $[0,1]$.

Now the sum constraint is rewritten as $$10U_1+20U_2+100U_3+80=100,$$ or
$$U_1+2U_2+10U_3=2.$$

We can sample uniformly over the relevant space by using the R package 'hitandrun', which "generates a Markov Chain whose stable state converges on a uniform distribution over a convex polytope."

I used this R code:

```
library(hitandrun)

# Sample uniformly from u1 + 2*u2 +10*u3 = 2 with
# 0 <= u1,u2,u3 <= 1
n <- 3
eq.constr <- list(
  constr = matrix(c(1,2,10),nrow=1,ncol=n),
  dir = '=',
  rhs = 2)

ineq.constr <- list(
  constr = rbind(-diag(n),diag(n)),
  dir = rep('<=',n*2),
  rhs = c(rep(0,n),rep(1,n)))

basis <- solution.basis(eq.constr)
transform <- createTransform(basis)
constr <- transformConstraints(transform,ineq.constr)
x0 <- createSeedPoint(constr,homogeneous=TRUE)
x <- har(x0,constr,500,transform=transform, homogeneous=TRUE)$samples

stopifnot(all.equal(x[,1]+2*x[,2],2-10*x[,3]))
stopifnot(all(x >= 0))
stopifnot(all(x <= 1))

str(x)
head(x)
x
```

Here is some sample output, where I've converted it back to your $X_1, X_2,$ and $X_3.$

```
   X1     X2      X3    Sum
11.5317 22.9209 65.5474 100
13.7872 21.5719 64.6409 100
16.0213 25.4983 58.4803 100
16.6402 26.5761 56.7837 100
14.5796 30.4687 54.9516 100
```